# Live USB works on win, problems on mac

Tags: gnome, 14.04, live-usb, gnome-tweak-tool

I have a live usb, Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I use it on PCs at school and on my intel mac at home with plop bootloader, using PlopKexec. I installed the live usb with unetbootin because the Ubuntu installer kept crashing. Persistence seems to work but on the mac none of my gnome themes work. The tweak-tool doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

So, I fixed it by deleting my `.config` directory. For some reason it was corrupted. I had to re-do all my settings, but the problem was unrelated to mac.

Answer (score 0):

The USB 'Live CD' you make for a PC will not work on your Mac and vice versa. For the Mac you can try:

http://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/

It will give you an explanation as well as a program to help.

You might also have better luck with a CD/DVD instead of USB stick.
good luck

Comment: My mac is intel based. Forgot to mention that. Edited post.